# Given a file, return a list of tuples representing the lines in the file on Python

Tags: python, file, tuples

I have a file called "sample.txt" and contains the following:

```
1 city1 85 100 0.05
2 city2 80 100 0.05
3 city3 34 100 0.32
```

I want to return a list of tuples representing the lines in the file.

The items should be of type `int` except for the name `string` 
and the weight `float`

So the result would be like this:

```
[(1, 'city1', 85, 100, 0.05), (2, 'city2', 80, 100, 0.05), (3, 'city3', 34, 100, 0.32)]
```

This is the code that I have until now:

```
def reader(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        arr = [tuple(line.split()) for line in f]
        return arr

print(reader("sample.txt"))
```

And the result is as follows:

```
[('1', 'city1', '85', '100', '0.05'), ('2', 'city2', '80', '100', '0.05'), ('3', 'city3', '34', '100', '0.32')]
```

As you can see all the items are `strings` but I want to put the numbers as `int` and the float numbers as `float` just like it appears above but I´m stuck and I don´y know what to do.

Can you help me please?

Thannks for advanced. 
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You can zip with the corresponding type, and use it to convert from the string.

```
def reader(filename):
    types = [int, str, int, int, float]
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [tuple(t(x) for t, x in zip(types, line.split())) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(a)
        return b if a == b else a
    except:
        return x

def reader(filename):
    lines = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for l in f:
            lines.append(tuple(map(convert, l.split())))
    return lines
```

Comment: Thank you very much